# Can't see ListViewItems added programatically to a ListView in a UserControl?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listview, user-controls

I have a ListView in a user control in details mode with one column. I've added an item through the designer and it displays fine. However, anything I add programatically just doesn't show up in the list. The ListView.Items.Count property is correct though.

I've copied the adding code and list view into the main form and everything displays fine.

```
// user control
public void AddFiles(IEnumerable<string> files)
{
    // this doesn't work - list view doesn't show any new files
    ListViewItem[] items = files.Select(file => new ListViewItem(file)).ToArray();
    listView1.Items.AddRange(items);
}

// main form
private void AddFiles(IEnumerable<string> files)
{
    // call to the user control
    fileList.AddFiles(files);

    // test code works correctly - can see the added files in the list view
    ListViewItem[] items = files.Select(file => new ListViewItem(file)).ToArray();
    listView1.Items.AddRange(items);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar function with a UserControl as follows:

```
using ListViewCollection = System.Windows.Forms.ListView.ListViewItemCollection;

void FillDirectories ( )
{
    IEnumerable<DirectoryInfo> pathDirInfos = currentPath.EnumerateDirectories ( );

    var dirItems = ( from d in pathDirInfos
                     select new ListViewItem
                     {
                         Name = d.Name,
                         Text = d.Name,
                     } )
                   .ToArray ( );

    ListViewCollection listItems = new ListViewCollection ( uxExplorerListView );
    listItems.AddRange ( dirItems );
}
```

The only difference I see is that I am creating a `ListView.ListViewItemColleciton` which passes the owning `ListView` control to the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

when  you do it programmatically you need to create at least one column first.